# How To Write Selenium Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am stuck here. I am trying a write Xpath for the following. I am trying to click "Browse". The ID is changing every time.

I have tried this as my Xpath:

```
//*[@id='ext-gen43']/em/span/span


<a id="ext-gen43" class="x-tab-right" href="#">
<em class="x-tab-left">
<span class="x-tab-strip-inner">
<span class="x-tab-strip-text ">Browse</span>
</span>
</em>
</a>
```

Comment: See this link http://hedleyproctor.com/2011/05/tutorial-writing-xpath-selectors-for-selenium-tests/

Comment: As the `id` is dynamic, as in it changes each time, you will not be able to use `id` as the beginning of your xpath selector. Instead, I suggest that you use the `class`. As such your xpath would look like: `//a[@class='x-tab-right']/em/span/span`

Answer (score 2):

## XPATH WRITING PLUGINS :

- Inorder to write xpath's by yourself you must **first install firebug
  and firepath plugins**, they are the plugins available for Firefox
  browser.
- You can also install **xpath checker** which is another plugin available for firefox. It's a awesome plugin because you can actually
  see the UI elements in the xpath checker as you are writing the
  xpath.

## EXAMPLE :

- Inorder to write xpath's by yourself you must following the child and parent hierarchy available in the HTML tab in firebug.

### STEPS :

- Hover on the element you want to write xpath for using the small blue arrow available in the firebug toolbar in the top left corner.
- Now click on the element, you would observe that the tag for the respective element in the firebug is highlighted.
- Say your tag looks like :-

---

```
   <label> class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name"> Your Name <label>
```

---

- So the xpath for respective tag would be :-
  **//label[@class="control-label col-sm-3"]**

*So the above xpath specifies //parent tag which is label and into the bracket we should specify the locator, locator can be id, class, name anything.*

**And in your case the xpath would be :-**

**//span[@class="x-tab-strip-text"]**

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried copy xpath for given element in your browser(check element -> copy xpath)?

Then delete id and check once again.

It should be easy if you know how to select element by xpath with given class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use firepath to get xpath. It`s addon for FireFox https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/firepath/

Comment: Could you add a code snippet to show how to use firepath in the provided example?

Comment: @JeroenKransen [link](http://selenium-by-arun.blogspot.com/2012/11/6-how-to-use-firepath.html) just choose XPath instead of CSS

Comment: I'm not the OP, my point is that a good SO answer includes code, not just links. Please update your answer to include some code, that should suffice without following any links.

Comment: @JeroenKransen ok, this was links to useful tool and short instruction. Does Mark`s answer good for you //a[@class='x-tab-right']/em/span/span  ?