# Java selenium xpath - getting all elements under a specific element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

this is a simplified HTML structure i'm searching through:

```
<div class="main">
...other stuff...
       <td class="child">44</td>
       <td class="child">59</td>
       <td class="child">11</td>
</div>
<div class="main">
...other stuff...
       <td class="child">5</td>
       <td class="child">14</td>
       <td class="child">98</td>
</div>
...this kind of structure repeats with similar numbers a few more times but with identical class names
```

I need to extract all the numbers under the first found main class so I've made a query to search for the first main, and all td's with the specific class under it. Can somebody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong since this query gives me all the numbers from all td's with class "child" in all "main" div's:

```
List<WebElement> koefi = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='main'][1]//td[@class='child']"));
```

What am I doing wrong or is my logic right but I'm missing some other parts of html which I haven't pasted here since the structure is too cumbersome..?

Thank You!!

p.s.:
I tried this also but again, I get contents of all td's with "child" class, and not only the first "main"..

```
List<WebElement> koefi = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[1][@class='main']//td[@class='child']"));
```

**UPDATE:**
I managed to solve my problem by first getting the first occurence of the "main" div which is by default found by the .findElement function:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[1][@id='main']"));
```

And then extracting with .findElements function the "child" classes:

```
List<WebElement> kk = element.findElements(By.className("child"));
```

I am still unable to figure out why doesn't the .findElements with my xpath work, or it works too well, it extracts every "main" class and not only the first one. And the original HTML is too big to paste here, so I don't want to bother you guys!!

Comment: Do you getting any error? can you please try :                                        java.util.List<WebElement> koefi = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='main'][1]//td[@class='child']"));

Comment: Are you sure all `<div class="main">` are siblings?

Comment: @Helping: I get a list of all the "child" elements, and my goal is to get "child" elements only under the first "main".. I imported java.util.List at the top of my file..

Comment: @Maroun: there is an underlying structure above the "main" container but, yes they are all in the same level, for example div1>div2>div3>main, and then again div1>div2>div3>main and so on..

Comment: @Hrvoje85 Does it have `class="main"` as well?

Comment: @Maroun no, "main" is actually a specific class name for that set of classes, and there doesn't exist a higher level div with the same class name

Comment: @Hrvoje85 - try to rename "main" then use updated xpath.

Comment: @HelpingHands how do you mean, rename it to what?

Comment: @HelpingHands the "main"'s are not direct siblings.. they are of the same level in the hierarchy

Comment: I mean like set class name "main-1"

Comment: then the result List is empty

Comment: I don't think this is fruitful. Please post more of the actual HTML to help us get the complete picture.

Comment: What is the parent element of this series of `<div class="main">` ? The element that comprises of all these div elements with class 'main'.

Comment: Try as I described, selecting through broweser, then delete specifics if needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951062/how-to-write-selenium-xpath/23952540#23952540 U could also use SeleniumIDE just to check your selection, still I find just using find element and check in script browser faster.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I've managed to get what I wanted, please see the original post UPDATE to see

Comment: @Subh I've managed to get what I wanted, please see the original post UPDATE to see

Comment: The xpath in the original question `//div[@class='main'][1]//td[@class='child']` contains a relative path which holds true for all your main classes.

Comment: **`And the original HTML is too big to paste here`**. You don't need to paste all the html. Please just paste the parent element of these all **divs with class main**. After that, it will be easier to figure out a better solutions.

Comment: @lost yes, thats why i tried //*[1][@class='main']//td[@class='child'] which i tought would give me the first occurence of div main on the page, right??

Comment: @Subh it's ok, I managed to get what I wanted so no need to paste all the contents here..

Comment: I am not aware of this syntax .. Let me do some research and get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much cleaner solution would be to first grab all the `div`s with class `main`, like so:

```
List<WebElement> allDivs = driver.findElements(By.className("main"));
```

Then, as you specified, find all the `td`s with class `child`, like so:

```
List<WebElement> tds = allDivs[0].findElements(By.className("child"));
```

After that, it is just a matter of iterating over all the "tds" and read out your values.

Comment: this is a great approach, thanks for the idea. I did it in a similar fashion, i got the first occurence of "main" with .findelement() and them got all "child" td's with .findelements(). but thank you very much for the idea!!

Answer (score 0):

You say in a comment that

> the "main"'s are not direct siblings

so I suspect you are falling foul of a common error related to the definition of `//` in XPath.  The path

```
//div[@class='main'][1]
```

does *not* select the first "main" div in the document.  The reason for this is that `//` is a shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` (including the leading and trailing slashes), so what this path actually means is

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::div[@class='main'][1]
```

When you see it fully expanded you realise that the `[1]` relates to the `child::` step and not the search for descendants, i.e. you'll get all the `div` elements in the document that have the class "main" *and* are the first div-with-class-main under their respective parent elements.  If your actual HTML is

```
<div>
  <div class="main">...</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="main">...</div>
</div>
```

then that XPath would select both of them (they're both the first under their parents).  If you do just want the first one in the document then you should use the `descendant::` axis

```
/descendant::div[@class='main'][1]
```

which will give you the first matching descendant only.

Comment: shouldn't this: //*[1][@class='main']//td[@class='child'] give me the first occurence of "main" also?

Comment: @Hrvoje85 predicates apply left to right - `//*[1][@class='main']` means every element in the document that is the first child element of its parent, and has the class main, as opposed to `//*[@class='main'][1]` which would be every element that is the first element-with-class-main in its parent.